# Auth::attempt doesn't work [Laravel]

Tags: authentication, laravel

Here is my issue :

I have a table users which is :

id username email password

Also, a model User, and when it comes to signup, everything's fine.

Now when I want to login here's my **view** :

```
@layout('main')

@section('content')


@if(Session::has('login_errors'))

<div class='alert alert-error'>Wrong ID</div>

@endif

{{Form::open('user/login', 'POST', array('class' => 'well inline-form'))}}

{{Form::token()}}


{{Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('class' => 'input-large', 'placeholder' => 'email'))}}
{{Form::password('password', array('class' => 'input-large', 'placeholder' => 'Mot de passe'))}}

{{Form::submit('Login', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'))}}

{{Form::close()}}

@endsection
```

And here is what I do in my **controller**

```
public function action_login()
{
    if(Auth::check()){return Redirect::to('user');}

    if(Request::method() == 'POST')
    {

        $credentials = array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            return Redirect::to('user');
        }

        else
        {

            return Redirect::to('user/login')->with_input()->with('login_errors', true);

        }
    }


    Section::inject('title', 'Login');

    return View::make('user.login');

}
```

It should work, yet it doesn't.

The bug is as follow : when I click the login button, my form pass to my controller and is read. I know my Input::get('username'), Input::get('password') are correct, and registered in db.

The problem is : Even tho my email/password are correct, I can't get Auth, and I get my message **Wrong ID**. I hope I was clear...

Things you should know :

I haven't changed Auth.php in config, so username is email

I hash the password when I signup with : 'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))

**EDIT and solution**

Ok, I figured it out !

First of all :

- I used Php 5.3.6 and Hash need 5.3.7 at least
- After that, I realized that in my db, password was 40 character max. I feel stupid

Hope it will help someone /thread

Comment: Can you please supply your routes?

Comment: My route is really simple : Route::controller(Controller::detect());

Answer (score 0):

For one, Controller::detect() is a flawed approach - and is advocated in numerous places not to take the shortcut and use that method. Specify every route you need - not only is it more readable, it's also easier to understand what's going on with requests.

If you haven't changed auth config, then that should mean that the username provided from the form should be someone's EMAIL, as that's what Auth will be checking against. So make sure this is the case. If you want to match against username, be sure to set that also.

Additionally, more information is required - you haven't really started what doesn't work, just that it doesn't work. What exactly, doesn't work? Make sure you follow my points above and it's still not working, we need more information/code. Atm, your bug report is rather flawed.

Comment: Ok, I know for the routes, but that's clearly not the problem here (I'm still learning Laravel)

I have clearly specify : "I haven't changed Auth.php in config, so username is email", so I know that I have to use the email as username, and that's what I do.

Now, my bug is as follow :

When I click on login, my form pass to my controller. Even if the username (email) and the password are correct, I still get the error I wrote in case the user write wrong username/password.

So, I tried to pass a username and password directly to Auth::attempt.

Doesn't work either..

Hope I'm clear :)

Comment: Unfortunately your report wasn't as clear as you thought, hence needing more info. Glad you figured it out though :)